# Google Sign In Exception Error swift

Tags: google-api, swift3, xcode8, google-signin, invalidargumentexception

I'm not getting the point where I'm making mistake while using Google SDK Login on custom button. The console is giving:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|'
>   *** First throw call stack:"

Even I have given Client ID too see images below:

[image]

I appreciate your responses.

Comment: Welcome to stack please post your code so that someone can test it.  Not a screen shot of your code.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: got answer    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "Your Client Id"  should be called before calling .signIn()   method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write **Client ID** in applicationdidfinish method of *AppDelegate* class or in viewDidLoad before the google signin delegating self.